# Read text file from specific word to stop from specific word in Java

Tags: java, arrays, filereader

I am new to Java programming, I have to read text file data from specific word to stop from specific word. See the below text file data here read data from account number 1056 and stop from next account number.

```
 1056 ACCT-NME-0360011056                10,710.00   680 TPO 002        10,710.00   680 TPO 001        10,710.00   680 TPO 001
                                               10,710.00   680 TPO 001
 1058 ACCT-NME-0360011058                 1,600.00   680 TPO 001         1,600.00   680 TPO 001         1,600.00   680 TPO 001
```

Comment: on that file is there one account per line or sometime it on single line and other time on more than line?

Comment: if you are new to java, why not start at the beginning and work your way up. do you know how to read a line? do you know how conditional statements work?

Comment: in this file one account will have more than one line so, I am not getting how to read line of account data.

Comment: I know how to read the file and condition statements, but stuck in if account has more than one line data how to read next line data.